# Does Couchbase document expiration affect documents which reference the expired document?

Tags: couchbase

Does Couchbase document expiration affect documents which reference the expired document ? E.g. in the "Modelling documents for retrieval" section of the documentation, there are crater documents which reference asteroid documents as follows:

"crater_id" : "crater1",
"on_asteroid" : "asteroidA"

Now, if the document with ID "asteroidA" were to expire, would that affect this record for this crater crater1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use TTL on members on couchbase documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665355/can-i-use-ttl-on-members-on-couchbase-documents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A document's TTL (expiry) affects just that document.